# ajax in asp.net not fetching from text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to retrieve data from textbox, when I but Id in the textbox it will retrieve rest of data in in other textbox here is my code:

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(int id)
{   
    testEntities db = new testEntities();
    List<Table_1> tb = db.Table_1.ToList();
    var c = tb.Find(m => m.id == id);
    return View(c);
}
```

view

```
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Table_1</h4>
    <hr />
    <form id="myForm">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.depart, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.depart, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.depart, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button type="button" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="btnSubmit">press here</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
    
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                debugger
                
    
                var data = $("#myForm").serialize();
    
                $.ajax({
    
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/Contact",
                    data: data,
                    success: function (response) {
                       
                    },
    
                });
            });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use almost the same codes:

```
@model FormSubmitWebApplication.Models.Student
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Table_1</h4>
    <hr />
    <form id="myForm">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button type="button" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="btnSubmit">press here</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

@section  scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            debugger


            var data = $("#myForm").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Contact",
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {

                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

The id could be passed to the controller. [image]

Could you show the debug view in the controller?